# How can I get photos 2 users are tagged in using the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am using the Facebook API/Opengraph and want to get a count of the number of images 2 people are tagged in. One of the two people is the current logged in user, who I have an access token for.

Is this possible? The docs for the /user/photos endpoints are a little sparse.

Comment: Iterate through all photos and check how many are tagged in each

Comment: There must be an easier way than that @WizKid - if the user has 100 photos, which is more than likely, that's the API quota instantly hit and the page would take a while to load.

Comment: No there is no other way

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? @mikemike

Comment: Nope. I'm not sure it's possible